# iOS app reported to be crashing by some end user. No clue on how to exploit crash report

Tags: ios, xcode, crash

Some end users report a crash on published application.
In spite of all our efforts, no way to reproduce it. And crash reports from Xcode do not help much.
All that we have is: "FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK"
See joined picture.

[see here details of the crash as reported in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNaUC.png)

Comment: This is hard to find. In most cases an outdated external library like Fabric, Crashlytics or Google Analytics was the reason. Maybe you should check the versions of such dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is only one external library which is used: DropBox. Indeed it could be outdated since we still have to update to their "v2" API.